# Restart lighttpd failed raspberry

Tags: raspberry-pi2, lighttpd

Hi i have a problem for installing lighttpd on a raspberry.

I have installed lighttpd in the righ way, and it worked but since i have reboot i have this message :

> sudo /etc/init.d/lighttpd restart [....] Restarting lighttpd (via
>   systemctl): lighttpd.serviceJob for lighttpd.service failed. See
>   'systemctl status lighttpd.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details. 
>   failed!
>
> systemctl status lighttpd.service ● lighttpd.service - Lighttpd Daemon
>   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/lighttpd.service; enabled)
>   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2017-06-18 07:55:58 UTC;
>   22min ago   Process: 12152 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/lighttpd -t -f
>   /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf (code=exited, status=255)
>
> journalctl -xn No journal files were found.

thanks for help

Answer (score 2):

Run: `sudo /usr/sbin/lighttpd -tt -f /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf` (lighttpd 1.4.40 and later) and see if that shows you an error at startup.  Next, run `sudo /usr/sbin/lighttpd -p -f /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf` to print the configuration and look for the location of the error log.  Look in the error log for why lighttpd is not starting.